# Reading offsets in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am going with manual offset commit on Kafka. Is there a way to get the list of offsets committed whenever I do consumer.commitOffsets(); 
P.S. I am using a high level consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what Kafka version or client (ie, language) you are using. Java high level consumer offers

```
KafkaConsumer#committed(TopicPartition partition);
```

to receive the latest committed offset for a partitions. Thus, you could call this after you did the commit.

https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

If you want to know the offsets before you are doing the commit, you need to get the offset for each last message per partition of the last `poll()`. Thus, after `poll()` when processing your records, you need to get this information via

```
ConsumerRecord#offset()
```

https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html